# Jboss multiple instances in Standalone mode on same pc

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We are using Jboss 7 App Server and we are trying run multiple server nodes on a single box and also on other box *basically 2 boxes which will have 2 each nodes of Jboss servers running).

My question is to have multiple nodes of Jboss Servers on a single box in Standalone mode. Should I have to copy server folder twice with port offsets?

Or is it ok to start servers just via port offset without having to copying server folder?

What is the best practice to have multiple server nodes running on the same box? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at running a managed domain instead of two separate servers? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-ManagedDomain

Answer (score 1):

Just create multiple copies of standalone directory(Example: standalone_PROD,standalone_SIT) so that we will have separate log files and deployment directories for each instance. And use below option while starting server instance:

```
-Djboss.server.base.dir=/path/to/standalone_SIT  <-- Location of standalone dir
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10   <-- PortOffset to avoid port conflict
```

Answer (score 0):

We have had two instances of jboss on the same computer over several years. Both instances were in the same domain. Each instance had its own port and of course lay in its own path. Our experiences were good.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many standalone instances you want on a machine, depending upon the resources available.
All you need to do is copy over the same folder twice and make changes in all the ports to be used in the standalone mode. Also If you are setting any parameters make sure they are according to the memory available on the machine.